# Extending CakePHP's AppController with functions from other classes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I wan't to extend the default AppController class by function from another class from the 'library' folder inside the application root.

On this moment I can reach the class and his function by adding a `@property` declaration above my class definition like below. But when I run the application it's returning a `Call to a member function showTest() on boolean` exception. Is this because I've not declared a namespace or something in that way?

```
// Default class inside 'root/src/Controller/'
/**
* Class    AppController
*
* @property testControl $testControl
*
* @package     App\Controller
*/
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event) : void
    {
       $this->testControl->showTest();
    }
}

// The class inside folder 'root/library/' 
class testControl
{
    public function showTest() {
        die("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, read the OOP chapter in the php manual and do some object oriented programming tutorials. Otherwise this would require a *very* long answer. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php The question shows a huge lack of fundamental knowledge. You need to understand the basics and concepts and be able to apply them first. Just throwing you a piece of code in will not help you in the long run. So I recommend you to learn how OOP works, which can't be taught in a short answer.

Comment: I know exactly how OOP works, but I don’t understand how I can use a function from another class thats not inside the src/controller folder but inside a library/vendor.

Comment: You clearly don't know "exactly how OOP works" if you think that adding an @property comment gives you access to other code.

Comment: Of course I know that you can’t implement or creating inherritance between classes by adding a @propperty. Those makes it easyer to program things. I only wan’t to know how you can add some functions from other classes to the appcontroller with CakePHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of the `testControl` object before calling the method:-

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) : void
{
    $testControl = new testControl;
    $testControl->showTest();
}
```

The PHP error you are seeing is because you haven't initiated the object and `$this->testControl` hasn't been defined.

You will also need to make sure you tell PHP where to find the `testControl` class by adding a `use` statement at the top of your file or referencing the namespace when initiating the object.